# How to denormalize two tables into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-modeling, data-manipulation

I have two tables and I am trying to denormalize two tables into one, I don't have any mapping between these two tables.

Cities

[image]

Persons

[image]

Jessy owns two stores in different cities, one in OR and another one in WA, John also owns two stores one in NY and another one in NJ.

I am trying to create a single table by denormalizing these two tables. is there a way we can denormalize these two tables into one?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you don't have a relationship between the tables, then there is no much that you can do.  How do you know what stores Jessy and John own?

Comment: So, what are you expected results here? There are several forms of denormalisation; which are you after? How do you know which stored Jessy owns, from the data you have provided?

Comment: Also, that first table's data looks very wrong. For example, both NY and NJ have a City ID of 2, and OR and WA a City ID of 4; if they are different cities, why do they have the same City ID?

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff, I was asked to answer this question in an interview, and  I wasn't sure if we could do that without any relationship between those tables.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create a junction table based on a list of name/city pairs?  If so:

```
select c.city_id, p.id as person_id
from (values ('Jessy', 'OR'), ('Jessy', 'WA'), . . .
     ) v(name, city) join
     cities c
     on v.city = c.city join
     persons p
     on v.name = p.name;
```